# Muttons Brewery in a bag kit - what to do with pressure release valve?

Tags: kits

I have a "brewery in a bag kit" that has a pressure release valve but I don't understand where this goes on the bag.

Comment: Are you refering to the yellow cap?  Do you have a link to the specific product?

Comment: Mine does not have a yellow cap but a valve, I worked it out that goes inside the whole at the top where the white cap was.